# Using a large capacity drive in windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, sata

I bought a 4TB Western Digital drive, and also have an external 3TB USB 3.0 drive.  I'm using that enclosure to test a bit.  Using USB 3.0, I can format both drives and use them- life is good.

But if I take either of the 3 or 4TB drives and actually hook them up to the SATA cables with power, one doesn't show at all, and the other says it needs to be formatted.

These are not boot disks, just data drives.

By all accounts I have seen, win8.1 shouldn't have a problem... but it's not working.

A smaller 1TB in that internal slot with the same sata cable and power plug works just fine.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I don't know enough for a full answer, but wasn't there something about GPT partitioning only being supported by 64-bit Windows? With >2TB drives, you need GPT to be able to access the full capacity; MBR (the old scheme, which dates back to the initial hard disk support in MS-DOS 2.0) caps out at 2 TB.

Comment: Yup, this is windows 8.1 64bit.  Should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there are different methods to store filesystems on a storage device; a device can be formatted without partition table, or it can have a MBR or GPT partition table. MBR does not support devices larger than 2TB. The short story is that Windows only supports GPT for large drives on SATA, and doesn't support GPT for USB mass storage.

I'm going out on a limb here, but I have seen Windows treat USB disks different from internal disks. In more technical terms, it would not recognise USB disks with GPT and it would not recognise internal disks without a partition table.  My guess here is that Windows formats your USB disks >2TB without a partition table and then doesn't recognise it via SATA because it lacks a partition table.

The bad news here is that I don't have a direct solution for you; you can always try reading the disk with Linux, which does not treat USB or SATA disks differently. But it's probably the easiest for you if you backup the drive, format it while it is connected in the way you intend to use it and restore the data.

Alternatively you can use Linux to format the drive with an MBR partition table, which Windows supports on both USB and SATA, but this will limit your filesystem to 2TB in size. Maybe you can also do this from Windows, I don't have a large drive available to test right now.

Comment: I'm more and more suspecting there is just something wrong with my machine.  I can't format ANY disk, even a VHD.  Ill post that as a separate question though.